# header toggle is not showing and i can't expand menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my html, css and js code below for side bar menu in bootstrap. the problem is is the header toggle and any other icon is not showing on the menu so i can't expand the menu also all the icons i used from box icons are not showing (also i imported     https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css) , is there a way to fix this?
thanks in advance

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, bodyId, headerId) =>{
    const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
    nav = document.getElementById(navId),
    bodypd = document.getElementById(bodyId),
    headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId)
    
    // Validate that all variables exist
    if(toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd){
    toggle.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    // show navbar
    nav.classList.toggle('show')
    // change icon
    toggle.classList.toggle('bx-x')
    // add padding to body
    bodypd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
    // add padding to header
    headerpd.classList.toggle('body-pd')
    })
    }
    }
    
    showNavbar('header-toggle','nav-bar','body-pd','header')
    
    /*===== LINK ACTIVE =====*/
    const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_link')
    
    function colorLink(){
    if(linkColor){
    linkColor.forEach(l=> l.classList.remove('active'))
    this.classList.add('active')
    }
    }
    linkColor.forEach(l=> l.addEventListener('click', colorLink))
    
    // Your code to run since DOM is loaded and ready
    });
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");

:root {
    --header-height: 3rem;
    --nav-width: 68px;
    --first-color: #4723D9;
    --first-color-light: #AFA5D9;
    --white-color: #F7F6FB;
    --body-font: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --z-fixed: 100
}

*,
::before,
::after {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
    position: relative;
    margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    font-family: var(--body-font);
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    transition: .5s
}

a {
    text-decoration: none
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--header-height);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    background-color: var(--white-color);
    z-index: var(--z-fixed);
    transition: .5s
}

.header_toggle {
    color: var(--first-color);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer
}

.header_img {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden
}

.header_img img {
    width: 40px
}

.l-navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -30%;
    width: var(--nav-width);
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--first-color);
    padding: .5rem 1rem 0 0;
    transition: .5s;
    z-index: var(--z-fixed)
}

.nav {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden
}

.nav_logo,
.nav_link {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 1rem;
    padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.5rem
}

.nav_logo {
    margin-bottom: 2rem
}

.nav_logo-icon {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_logo-name {
    color: var(--white-color);
    font-weight: 700
}

.nav_link {
    position: relative;
    color: var(--first-color-light);
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    transition: .3s
}

.nav_link:hover {
    color: var(--white-color)
}

.nav_icon {
    font-size: 1.25rem
}

.show {
    left: 0
}

.body-pd {
    padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 1rem)
}

.active {
    color: var(--white-color)
}

.active::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: var(--white-color)
}

.height-100 {
    height: 100vh
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        margin: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem) 0 0 0;
        padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
    }

    .header {
        height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem);
        padding: 0 2rem 0 calc(var(--nav-width) + 2rem)
    }

    .header_img {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px
    }

    .header_img img {
        width: 45px
    }

    .l-navbar {
        left: 0;
        padding: 1rem 1rem 0 0
    }

    .show {
        width: calc(var(--nav-width) + 156px)
    }

    .body-pd {
        padding-left: calc(var(--nav-width) + 188px)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link href="/assets/images/logo.png" rel="icon" type="icon"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="js/scripts.js"> </script>
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css'>
    

</head>

<body id="body-pd">
    <header class="header" id="header">
        <div class="header_toggle"> <i class='bx bx-menu' id="header-toggle"></i> </div>
    </header>
    <div class="l-navbar" id="nav-bar">
        <nav class="nav">
            <div> <a href="#" class="nav_logo"> <i class='bx bx-layer nav_logo-icon'></i> <span class="nav_logo-name">BBBootstrap</span> </a>
                <div class="nav_list"> <a href="#" class="nav_link active"> <i class='bx bx-grid-alt nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Dashboard</span> </a> <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-user nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Users</span> </a> <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-message-square-detail nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Messages</span> </a> <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Bookmark</span> </a> <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-folder nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Files</span> </a> <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-bar-chart-alt-2 nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Stats</span> </a> </div>
            </div> <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-log-out nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">SignOut</span> </a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--Container Main start-->
    <div class="height-100 bg-light">
        <h4>Main Components</h4>
    </div>
    <!--Container Main end-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the following code in your head tag. Found this cdn link from there official web page.

```
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Change your bootstrap cdn with this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

And add some css code

```
.h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

MUST work